# how to apply a modification to thirdparty git packages across releases?

Tags: git, github

There's an opensource thirdparty project on Github. I have an internal git repo where I need to maintain some change to it (it won't be pushed to github).

What's the best way for me to maintain my change across new releases of the thirdparty project? Assuming my change is relatively localized, is there a way to go through a series of error-proof steps to make the same changes to the same code every time I need to update the thirdparty project to the latest release?

Comment: Couldn't you fork their code?

Comment: As @NightShadeQueen suggested, fork their code, and then [sync your fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) as the 3rd party project is updated.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I read more on forking, and I think this is the way to go.